# Divergence of a series given another divergence series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Honestly, It is a homework problem.

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ be a divergent series with positive terms.
We have to examine whether the following are true or false

i) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{1+n^2x_n}$ is convergent

ii) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x_n}{1+nx_n} $ is divergent

I am able to do the first one by comparing with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n^2} $

But the second one I am unable to do.

If $x_n$ $\geq$ $1$ then of course it is divergent. But in general I am unable to do it.

Please help.

I really do not want the full
steps.

I just need a hint.

(I have tried by Comparison test or its limiting form)

Comment: @Doug If I am not mistaken the inequality is obtained by assuming that $x_n >1$ which may not be so. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct.  I deleted my comment.. Still struggling with it myself :)

Comment: Analyze cases when $nx_n\ge1$ or $nx_n<1$

Comment: Another hint: $x_n=1$ seldom and $x_n=2^{-n}$ otherwise.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc I am still trying to analyse those hints. For $nx_n\geq1$ it can be compared to the series of $1/(2n)$ which is divergent. For $nx_n<1$, I am still trying

Comment: Perhaps my first hint was misleading: split the indices into two subsets according to $nx_n\ge 1$ and $nx_n<1.$ You should be able to conclude that the terms of the series are located between ${1\over 2}\min(1/n,x_n)$ and $\min(1/n,x_n)$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Okay. I got it but that is like a full solution. Hehe. Thank you so much for your help. I wish I could accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: No problem. If you like a challenge show that if $x_n$ is decreasing and $\sum.x_n=\infty$ than the series $\sum \min(x_n,1/n)$ is always divergent unlike in the case when $x_n$ does need to be decreasing.

Comment: Okay I will try.

Comment: @Koro yes it does. Thank you